# How to get a string array from a computer to an android application

Tags: android, web-services

I have written a Java program on my computer that searches on the net and updates a String array based on what it finds. This program will be running constantly to maintain accurate data.

What I need to do is get this string array from my computer to an android app using the Internet. I attempted to do this through the google docs api but im not sure thats the best route considering its such a simple piece of data.

I am new to android and interfacing with the net so I thought I would ask if anyone knew of a simple way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into using Google's Appengine and/or Android C2DM (Cloud to Device Messaging). Either that or setting up a server on your local machine and use C2DM or have the Android app poll the server, but that seems like a real PITA and is most likely overkill.